# Javascript - how to fix the video screen to be stretched width and height without making cutting of picture by height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-chrome

This is not correct, i am trying to set a video screen completely to 100% width and 100% height. But then on a larger resolution it does not display properly the height (get out from the view).

> The following aspect ration is working but the problem is it makes wrong (black on left and right):

[image]

```
window.onresize = function(){
  var aspectRatio;
  if (remoteVideo.style.opacity === '1') {
    aspectRatio = remoteVideo.videoWidth/remoteVideo.videoHeight;
  } else if (localVideo.style.opacity === '1') {
    aspectRatio = localVideo.videoWidth/localVideo.videoHeight;
  } else {
    return;
  }

  var innerHeight = this.innerHeight;
  var innerWidth = this.innerWidth;
  var videoWidth = innerWidth < aspectRatio * window.innerHeight ?
                   innerWidth : aspectRatio * window.innerHeight;
  var videoHeight = innerHeight < window.innerWidth / aspectRatio ?
                    innerHeight : window.innerWidth / aspectRatio;
  containerDiv = document.getElementById('container');
  containerDiv.style.width = videoWidth + 'px';
  containerDiv.style.height = videoHeight + 'px';
  containerDiv.style.left = (innerWidth - videoWidth) / 2 + 'px';
  containerDiv.style.top = (innerHeight - videoHeight) / 2 + 'px';
};
```

> Tried to modify this but still when the width increase then the height get cut off also while using `webkitRequestFullScreen();` the whole width and height is broken, its not doing accurate.

```
window.onresize = function(){
  var aspectRatio;
  if (remoteVideo.style.opacity === '1') {
    aspectRatio = remoteVideo.videoWidth/remoteVideo.videoHeight;
  } else if (localVideo.style.opacity === '1') {
    aspectRatio = localVideo.videoWidth/localVideo.videoHeight;
  } else {
    return;
  }

  var innerHeight = this.innerHeight;
  var innerWidth = this.innerWidth;
  var videoWidth = innerWidth < aspectRatio * window.innerHeight ?
                   innerWidth : aspectRatio * window.innerHeight;
  var videoHeight = innerHeight < window.innerWidth / aspectRatio ?
                    innerHeight : window.innerWidth / aspectRatio;
  containerDiv = document.getElementById('container');
  //containerDiv.style.width = videoWidth + 'px';
  containerDiv.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
  containerDiv.style.height = videoHeight + 'px';
  //containerDiv.style.left = (innerWidth - videoWidth) / 2 + 'px';
  //containerDiv.style.top = (innerHeight - videoHeight) / 2 + 'px';
};
```

***Expected output is (on resize or maximize or full-screen):***

[image]

Can anyone please suggest, i am completely lost, not able to make accurate expected output.

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/2m8ay/

Comment: I would think twice about stretching the video to fit

Answer (score 0):

You can try css for this:

```
video { 
       width:305px; 
       height:160px;  
       background:blue; 
    }
```

If video poster contains image then,

```
video { 
   width:305px; 
   height:160px;  
   background:transparent url('poster.jpg') no-repeat 0 0; 
   -webkit-background-size:cover; 
   -moz-background-size:cover; 
   -o-background-size:cover; 
   background-size:cover; 
}
```

But, this is useful only when you have very fixed amount of videos. Otherwise you will need to do inline css to reset the background image there.

**Update with your solution** : http://jsfiddle.net/2m8ay/1/

Comment: But i have it in PoPup window, and user is resizing it and also trying to maximize it. How can it be accurately streched. without losing height image.

Comment: you should show your POC then, at least HTML you are writing.

Comment: I tried your code but its not working , when i resize the window its not full screen and also when i maximize the screen its not scaling accruately.